How to Create a Version Name in Poetry that Includes Feature Names and is Compatible with ECR
I am working on a Python project using Poetry for dependency management and need to define version names that also indicate specific feature branches. These versions need to be compatible with AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) for Docker image tagging. I would like to include a feature name directly in the version, for example:
1.0.0.myAmazingFeature1

However, I am facing challenges with versioning conventions that need to comply with both Poetry's adherence to PEP 440 and Docker's tagging rules. What is an acceptable naming format that allows including the feature name within the version number while being valid for both Poetry and ECR?
Any guidance or examples on structuring version names in this context would be greatly appreciated.
